# Any way to do "real-time" unit conversion in web application

Tags: javascript, php, real-time, unit-conversion

I want to build a website that allows the user to convert `Hz` to `bpm` (note however that my question concerns all sort of unit conversion). I am using PHP and am hosting my website on Apache.

So, I was wondering if it was possible to "bind" an input field to an HTML element, like we do in WPF developement where you can bind an input area to a WPF element, and apply some sort of data conversion so if the user types `12 bpm`, the bound element will automaticly and immediately display `0.2 Hz`. If the user then adds a "0" so `120 bpm` will be automaticly and immediately converted to `2 Hz`.

The effect I am trying to describe can also be noted on this very forum : as I type my question, I can see a "real-time" final version of my text.

How is this achieved? Is there any way to do it with PHP? I know of AJAX but I would really prefer to avoid using Javascript to hold my math functions. Correct me if I am wrong but I think this could be accomplished with Node.js? Should I consider migrating to Node?

Comment: No need to query the server side for this, you should just do the calculations and show the result with plain old normal client side javascript

Comment: look into <input>'s `input` event. lots of "mvc" frameworks can make this trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just the DOM and JavaScript, you can use the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) on a text field to receive an immediate callback when its value changes as the result of user action:

```
document.querySelector("selector-for-the-field").addEventListener("input", function() {
    // Code here to do and display conversion
}, false);
```

Example (centigrade/Celsuis to Fahrenheit):

```js
var f = document.getElementById("f");
document.querySelector("#c").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var value = +this.value;
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    value = (value * 9) / 5 + 32;
    f.innerHTML = value;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
  Enter centigrade:
  <input type="text" id="c">
</label>
</div>
<div>
  Fahrenheit: <span id="f"></span>
</div>
```

Stepping back, yes, there are dozens of libraries and frameworks that provide MVC/MVVM/MVM/whatever-the-acronym-is-this-week in the browser. A short list of current popular ones: React, Angular, Vue, Knockout, ... Note that these are not magic, they're just code written in JavaScript (or something like TypeScript or Dart or CoffeeScript that compiles to JavaScript) that use the DOM the covers.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware you could do it in plain old JavaScript !

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example of real-time "inches to cm" conversion.

Note for this example to work, you will need to include jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Inches</label>
    <input type="text" id="user_input" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Centimeters</label>
    <input type="text" id="result" readonly />
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user_input').on('propertychange input keyup', function(){
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        $('#result').val(thisVal * 2.54);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/captain_theo/t10z01cm/

You can expand that for any type of conversion.

Check my updated fiddle that includes Hz to bpm also:

https://jsfiddle.net/captain_theo/t10z01cm/1/

Cheers, Theo